# UIActionSheet crashes on iPad swift

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I have the following button action in a toolbar:

```
  @IBAction func share(sender: AnyObject) {
        let modifiedURL1 = "http://www.declassifiedandratified.com/search.html?q=\(self.searchBar.text)"
        let modifiedURL = modifiedURL1.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "%20", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Share", message: "Share your findings", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
        let twBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Twitter", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (alert) -> Void in
            if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeTwitter){
                var twitterSheet:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
                twitterSheet.setInitialText("Look what I found on Declassified and Ratified: \(modifiedURL)")
                self.presentViewController(twitterSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to a Twitter account to share.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }

        let fbBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Facebook", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (alert) -> Void in
            if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook){
                var facebookSheet:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
                facebookSheet.setInitialText("Look what I found on Declassified and Ratified: \(modifiedURL)")
                self.presentViewController(facebookSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to a Facebook account to share.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
        let safariBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Open in Safari", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (alert) -> Void in
            let URL = NSURL(string: modifiedURL)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(URL!)
        }
        let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) { (alert) -> Void in
            println("Cancel Pressed")
        }

        let textBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Message", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (alert) -> Void in
            if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()) {
                let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()
                controller.body = "Look what I found on Declassified and Ratified: \(modifiedURL)"
                controller.messageComposeDelegate = self
                self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }


        alert.addAction(twBtn)
        alert.addAction(fbBtn)
        alert.addAction(safariBtn)
        alert.addAction(textBtn)
        alert.addAction(cancelButton)
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

However, this code crashes when called on an iPad with a sigbart crash (that is all I can see in the console). I see this is a common problem but the other solutions have not worked for me. I even set the version to the latest iOS and that didn't fix it. Can someone explain?

Comment: Post the symbolicated crash log. And if it crashes in the simulator, indicate which line it crashes at.

Comment: @RoboticCat it crashed in the simulator but doesn't give me a line

Comment: You should worry more about why you cannot see the error message, which says "UIPopoverPresentationController should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs". The fact that you are not seeing it means there is some hole in your understanding of Xcode. This is a very, very helpful error message; it tells you exactly what is wrong. But you need to learn how to see it.

Comment: You should click around and try to see the error message! It's there, I assure you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On an iPad, an action sheet is a popover. Therefore you *must* give its UIPopoverPresentationController a `sourceView` and `sourceRect`, or `barButtonItem`, so that it has something to attach its arrow to.

Comment: so like:  if let popoverController = alertController.popoverPresentationController {
    popoverController.barButtonItem = sender
}